# Duplicate entry exception while trying to create new job

Tags: java, mariadb, quartz

We're using quartz for scheduling jobs with MariaDB on beneath in a setup of a few nodes. We're also using it as a queue system. The most important reason for that is that we already have quartz in our service, and we do not have any queue just yet.

We're getting a lot of requests, very often at the same time with the same id of a business entity, which is used to generate job name for the sake of uniqueness.

```
        try {
            quartzServce.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
            log.info("job: {} has been scheduled", id);
        } catch (ObjectAlreadyExistsException ex) {
            log.warn(DUPLICATE_ENTRY_MESSAGE, job.getKey(), trigger.getKey());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
```

the quartzService.scheduleJobs is simply:

```
    public void scheduleJob(JobDetail jobDetail, Trigger trigger) throws SchedulerException {
        schedulerFactory.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    }
```

As you can see we're catching ObjectAlreadyExistsException and silence it down on a Warn level, as we do not treat it as errors, but from time to time we still get SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException wrapped in JobPersistenceException with a message:

```
Couldn't store job: (conn=435654) Duplicate entry '{our key is over here}' for key 'PRIMARY' [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: (conn=435654) Duplicate entry '{our key is over here}' for key 'PRIMARY']
```

What I assume is that between existence check, and the actual insert the other node manages to insert a row for the same id.

As I'm not really a fan of checking the message in an exception for something like "Duplicated entry" and silence the exception down with a warn level on that condition, I'm looking for another solution, maybe quartz configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking if the job exists or not before calling `quartzServce.scheduleJob`.
Using
`scheduler.checkExists(...)`

Not sure if thats what you were looking for.
But it sounds like you are gonna need a lock of some kind on this business entity id. So only one node at a time tries to schedule it.
You can save the distinct entity ids in a table before scheduling jobs for them. And let your nodes pick them up with a lock so that particular entity id is not visible to other nodes.